# Program Status Registers ARM Cortex-M4

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

I would like some help understanding the program status register.

I have a couple simple instructions below to test what will happen to the xPSR.

After I execute `adds r0,r1` my xPSR is:

1000001000000000000000000000000

My first confusion is, why is it 1?

My understanding of it is that the MSB is N, then Z,C,V.

N is only set if the result is negative, so I don't understand why I'm getting a 1 there.  The second one would be Z, that should be set because the result is 0.

After I execute adds r2,r3, I get:

10000001000000000000000000000000

So my question is, what is the proper way to read the binary number that is set in the xPSR?

```
    .syntax unified
    .text
    .global main

main:
        mov r0,#0
        mov r1,#0
        adds r0,r1
        mov r2,#0
        mov r3,#-1
        adds r2,r3


    .data
    .end
```

Comment: It looks like your debugger is playing tricks on you and fails to show leading zeroes.  The bit that is set to 1 is the Z bit, not the N bit.  The N bit is clear, but not shown (leading zero).  Configure your debugger to show leading zeroes to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Your first xPSR value is actually `01000 001 0000 0000 000000 0 000000000` (note the leading zero).  That's a 32-bit word, whereas the value you presented is 31 bits.  Most likely, your debugger is not set up to print out leading zeros, as noted by @fuz in a comment.  I've divided the number up in this way to be consistent with the fields of the APSR, EPSR and IPSR as shown in the [ARMv7-M Architecture Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0403/latest/) (section B1.4.2).

The important bits are the top five: `01000` corresponds to `NZCVQ`, or the negative, zero, carry, overflow and saturation flags respectively.  In your case the zero flag is set, indicating that `r0+r1=0`, which is true.

In your second example the xPSR value is `10000 001 0000 0000 000000 0000000000`, and the negative flag is indeed set.  Note that this does not necessarily indicate a negative result; there is nothing to indicate whether a value is signed or unsigned at the CPU level and this interpretation is in the hands of the programmer.  The negative flag indicates that *if the result is treated as a signed number then its value is negative*, which is true for `r2+r3` in your example.